# internal error in breqn package with dseries/dmath* pair

Tags: breqn

As an experiment, I took some equations that I'd manually split using aligned like so:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:fourierSeries:30}
\begin{aligned}
\int_a^b \phi(x) e^{-i \omega m x} dx
&= \sum c_k \int_a^b e^{i \omega (k -m) x} dx \\
&= c_m (b - a) + \sum_{k \ne m} \frac{e^{i \omega(k-m) b} - e^{i \omega(k-m)a}}{i \omega (k -m)}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

and switched it to dseries/dmath* in a way that I thought ought to have been allowed:

```
\begin{dseries}\label{eqn:fourierSeries:30a}
\begin{dmath*}
\int_a^b \phi(x) e^{-i \omega m x} dx
= \sum c_k \int_a^b e^{i \omega (k -m) x} dx 
= c_m (b - a) + \sum_{k \ne m} \frac{e^{i \omega(k-m) b} - e^{i \omega(k-m)a}}{i \omega (k -m)}
\end{dmath*}
\end{dseries}
```

but get the error:

```
Package breqn Error: eq@repack penalty neq 0,1,2,3.
```

if I do this.  It turns out that I can just use dmath like so as a work around:

```
\begin{dmath}\label{eqn:fourierSeries:30b}
\int_a^b \phi(x) e^{-i \omega m x} dx
= \sum c_k \int_a^b e^{i \omega (k -m) x} dx 
= c_m (b - a) + \sum_{k \ne m} \frac{e^{i \omega(k-m) b} - e^{i \omega(k-m)a}}{i \omega (k -m)}
\end{dmath}
```

That numbers the set of equalities as one equation so that actually does exactly what I want.  However, from the documentation, it doesn't look like what I did should be illegal.  For example, the following (more subequation like form) also doesn't compile:

```
\begin{dseries}\label{eqn:fourierSeries:30c}
\begin{dmath*}
a = b + c
\end{dmath*}
\begin{dmath*}
a = b + c
\end{dmath*}
\end{dseries}
```

Here's a complete latex doc that demonstrates the error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

% original manually split: 
%
%\begin{equation}\label{eqn:fourierSeries:30}
%\begin{aligned}
%\int_a^b \phi(x) e^{-i \omega m x} dx
%&= \sum c_k \int_a^b e^{i \omega (k -m) x} dx \\
%&= c_m (b - a) + \sum_{k \ne m} \frac{e^{i \omega(k-m) b} - e^{i \omega(k-m)a}}{i \omega (k -m)}.
%\end{aligned}
%\end{equation}

% works    
%    \begin{dmath}\label{eqn:fourierSeries:30b}
%    \int_a^b \phi(x) e^{-i \omega m x} dx
%    = \sum c_k \int_a^b e^{i \omega (k -m) x} dx 
%    = c_m (b - a) + \sum_{k \ne m} \frac{e^{i \omega(k-m) b} - e^{i \omega(k-m)a}}{i \omega (k -m)}
%    \end{dmath}

% both of these appear to break breqn           
\begin{dseries}\label{eqn:fourierSeries:30a}
\begin{dmath*}
\int_a^b \phi(x) e^{-i \omega m x} dx
= \sum c_k \int_a^b e^{i \omega (k -m) x} dx 
= c_m (b - a) + \sum_{k \ne m} \frac{e^{i \omega(k-m) b} - e^{i \omega(k-m)a}}{i \omega (k -m)}
\end{dmath*}
\end{dseries}

\begin{dseries}\label{eqn:fourierSeries:30a}
\begin{dmath*}
a = b + c
\end{dmath*}
\begin{dmath*}
a = b + c
\end{dmath*}
\end{dseries}

\end{document}
```

Do I misunderstand the point of the breqn dseries environment, or does it just not work?

Comment: not sure immediately why it breaks (I get `! Dimension too large.` on your MWE) but `dseries` doesn't seem to be the environment you want here it starts  in _text_ mode and is for making a sequence of in-line equations separated by text. seems like you'd just want dmath or to group them, dgroup

Comment: perhaps the error is version dependent.  I've got:

Package: breqn 2012/05/10 v0.98b Breaking equations

<If you convert your comment to an answer, I could accept it.>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, posting this as a sort of non-answer. May try to trace later (the error difference at least)

not sure immediately why it breaks (I get `! Dimension too large.` on your MWE) but dseries doesn't seem to be the environment you want here it starts in text mode and is for making a sequence of in-line equations separated by text. seems like you'd just want `dmath` or to group them, `dgroup` I used an older version but I'll update later and comment of it makes any real difference  `Package: breqn 2009/08/07 v0.98a Breaking equations`